# Is it possible custom classes to be added to the table element of bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView?

Tags: yii, yii-booster

When I use 'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table-bordered table-condensed'),
the custom classes were added to the wrapper div and not to the table element

```
<div id="contact-grid" class="table-bordered table-condensed">
<div class="summary">Displaying 1-6 of 6 results.</div>
<table class="items table">
<thead>
<tr>
```

Thanks!

**Update:** 
As end result I need the following:

```
<div id="contact-grid">
<div class="summary">Displaying 1-6 of 6 results.</div>
<table class="items table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
```

**Answer:**

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'contact-grid',
...
'itemsCssClass'=>'table-borde‌​red table-condensed',
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row?

```
'rowCssClassExpression'=>'(($data->live==1) ? "anotherclass" : "myclass")',
```

Comment: I need to add a custom style only to the table element, like this <table class="items table table-bordered table-condensed">

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`itemsCssClass`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#itemsCssClass-detail):

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('itemsCssClass'=>'table-bordered table-condensed'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That gave me a good direction. That what works is <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array('itemsCssClass'=>'table-bordered table-condensed',